# Como recuperar caminho de arquivo após aberto com fopen?

Tags: php, stream-de-arquivos, fopen, resources

Estou abrindo arquivos com fopen normal:

```
$arquivo =fopen('/var/www/projeto/teste/texto.txt');
```

e lá na frente eu não tenho mais acesso ao `texto.txt` e só tenho o `$arquivo` tem como eu tirar esse caminho do resource? *

as soluções que achei só me trouxeram :

```
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => stream
    [2] => inode/x-empty
    [3] => Resource id #93
    [4] => 
)
```

que são as seguintes funções respectivamente

```
[
is_resource($arquivo),
get_resource_type($arquivo),
mime_content_type($arquivo),
$handle,finfo_file($arquivo)
]
```

alguém sabe se é possível e se tem alguma forma?

(se não ficou claro: eu quero pegar o caminho: `/var/www/projeto/teste/texto.txt` de $arquivo).

trecho reproduzível:(crie um texto.txt)

```
<?php

$arquivo = fopen('texto.txt')

print_r([is_resource($arquivo),get_resource_type($arquivo),mime_content_type($arquivo),$arquivo,finfo_file($arquivo)],true);
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível usando a função [`stream_get_meta_data(resource $stream): array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php), mas definir uma variável global, constante ou acessível ao escopo já resolverá:

```
$caminho = '/var/www/foo/bar/baz.txt';

...

$handle = fopen($caminho, 'r');

...

echo 'Caminho: ', $caminho, "\n";
```

Isso já resolveria todo o problema, mas de qualquer forma vou explicar como usar o `stream_get_meta_data`, pois ele pode ser útil para outros *streams* disponíveis em PHP.

Se fizer algo como:

```
$stream = fopen('/var/www/projeto/teste/texto.txt', 'r');

print_r(stream_get_meta_data($stream));
```

Vai retornar um Array contendo diversas informações, no caso a que você deseja é o `uri`, exemplo de resultado:

```
C:\Users\inphinit\Desktop>php meta_data.php
Array
(
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
    [wrapper_type] => plainfile
    [stream_type] => STDIO
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 1
    [uri] => C:\Users\inphinit\Desktop\meta_data.php
)
```

Então assim obterá só o resultado que lhe interessa:

```
$uri = stream_get_meta_data($stream)['uri'];
```

É importante notar que se o caminho definido em fopen() for relativo e não absoluto o uri vai retornar o caminho relativo apenas, ou seja, não virá completo e também não irá tratar os separadores (`\\` e `/`) e nem níveis de pastas (`.` e `..`), vai ser exibido exatamente como passou no primeiro parâmetro exemplo:

```
$stream1 = fopen('foo/bar.txt', 'r');
echo 'URI: ', stream_get_meta_data($stream1)['uri'], "\n";

$stream2 = fopen('../../foo/./bar.txt', 'r');
echo 'URI: ', stream_get_meta_data($stream2)['uri'], "\n";
```

Retornando:

> URI: foo/bar.txt
>
> URI: ../../foo/./bar.txt

Se estiver em Windows e for usar `__dir__` para obter o caminho completo atual do script para localizar outro arquivo fazendo isso:

```
$stream = fopen(__dir__ . '/foo/bar.txt', 'r');

echo 'URI: ', stream_get_meta_data($stream)['uri'], "\n";
```

Retornará algo como:

> URI: C:\Users\inphinit\Desktop/foo/bar.txt

Note que os separadores estão exatamente como o `__dir__` passou concatenando com o caminho do arquivo que foi passado manualmente.